# How do I move an item from one menu to another?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

In the Visual Studio designer, how do you move a menu item from one menu to another?

I would assume drag and drop would work, but it seems to only work within a menu for me.

I usually resort to editing the .Designer.cs files by hand.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right-click, cut, and paste works just fine for me.

Comment: WARNING! The menu action is lost when you do that. 1. Copy the action from the properties and paste to a temp document; 2. Cut the menu item; 3. Paste the menu item in the new location; 4: Copy the action from the temp doc and paste into the properties

Comment: @DavideAndrea is correct.  The right-click, cut, paste approach does not carry over the menu choice's event handler(s).  The event handlers are not lost, they are just not included with the cut/paste approach.  To play it safe, copy the properties from the form's designer.cs module before using the cut/paste, perform the cut/paste, then update designer.cs to restore the event handler method(s) that were lost.  I am using VS 2019 with a .NET Framework 4.6.2 project.